# Qt QDomElement performance issue

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I'm writing an application for working with [GPX files](http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp) and I'm having performance issues when using the QDomElement class to read large XML documents. Files with GPS paths containing thousands of waypoints can take half a minute to load.

This is my code for reading paths (routes or tracks):

```
void GPXPath::readXml(QDomElement &pathElement)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pathElement.childNodes().count(); ++i)
    {
        QDomElement child = pathElement.childNodes().item(i).toElement();
        if (child.nodeName() == "trkpt" ||
            child.nodeName() == "rtept")
        {
            GPXWaypoint wpt;
            wpt.readXml(child);
            waypoints_.append(wpt);
        }
    }
}
```

When analysing the code with Apple's Instruments I noticed that QDomNodeListPrivate::createList() is responsible for most of the computing time and it is being called by both QDomNodeList::count() and QDomNodeList::item().

It appears that this is not an efficient way of iterating through the child elements of a QDomElement as the list seems to be re-generated for every operation. What approach should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this instead

```
void GPXPath::readXml(QDomElement &pathElement)
{
    QDomElement child = pathElement.firstChildElement();
    while (!child.isNull())
    {
        if (child.nodeName() == "trkpt" ||
            child.nodeName() == "rtept")
        {
            GPXWaypoint wpt;
            wpt.readXml(child);
            waypoints_.append(wpt);
        }
        child = child.nextSiblingElement();
    }
}
```

Turns out it is a factor 15 faster. I might be able to do it even faster by using SAX, but this will do for now.

Comment: I can confirm this has been a great improvement also in my app. I passed from 10 to 2 seconds of parsing time. As you said the problem is the QDomNodeList::count() method that calls QDomNodeListPrivate::createList() ...terribly slow.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using  [QT SAX](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/xml-sax.html) instead of DOM.  SAX parsers typically don't load the whole XML document into memory and are useful in cases such as yours